# Adding Play Stop Pause icons to iPhone Media player app

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, media-player

I have built a player app.  It has play, stop, pause rewind and ff buttons.

Where would I find 'stock' icons for the buttons?  Eg. the same ones used on the YouTube app and apparently all the other 'mainstream' player applications.

Also, when I go from stop to play or pause, there's a white 'flash' that happens behind the button.  Is this something I create programatically behind the buttons?

I may be making something difficult out of something easy.  I just don't want to create 'custom' versions if there real ones are readily available in the package.

Comment: the 'white flash' is a result of enabling 'shows touch on highlight' in Interface Builder or setting `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` to `YES` programatically

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.  It's always the little things that I seem to trip up on.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed there's been quite a few views of this page, and wanted to update the limited success I had.

I discovered an excellent website called [Glyphish.com](http://glyphish.com/) which has an incredible selection of artwork.

Hope this helps.